# How do I remove the username from my mac terminal prompt?

Tags: macos, terminal

I would like to remove my mac's username from the terminal and ideally just have the directory and $ on the line.

I've tried going into preferences and setting the shell to run command:

```sh
PS1 = "\ w \ $"; clear;
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: https://xta.github.io/HalloweenBash/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Try anyone from the below options,

**Option 1:**

1. Open the preferences in the terminal (top right)
2. Goto the shell tab and copy/paste the command `export PS1="\W \$"; clear;`
3. Restart the terminal and should work

OR

**Option 2:**
This will show directory and $ as a prompt

```
   echo "export PS1='\W \$'" >> ~/.bash_profile
    . ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

When assigning a variable, there can't be whitespace around the `=` sign.

Try removing it: `PS1="\ w \ $"`

Also, if you're using `zsh` on your Mac, the `\w` doesn't seem to work. Try using `$(pwd)` for the current working directory instead.